# Выгрузка таблицы с интервалом 15 минут

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется таблица в Oracle

PROCESS_NAME, START_DTTM, END_DTTM

Необходимо по полю START_DTTM вывести количество процессов с интервалом 15 минут, то есть посчитать сколько процессов отрабатывает за 15 минут

Comment: Отнимаем от значения поля некий штамп времени, взятый за базу, потом конвертируем его в минуты и делим на 15 с отбрасыванием дробной части. По полученному группируем.